# error deleting row from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have written syntax to delete a row from a MYSQL database. This works fine however i am now moving this to another page (copied and pasted) and for some reason it will not work on the new page

I'm not sure how to add error reporting so just get `server error`

Here is the code

```
<?php

$prodID = $_GET["q"];

if ($prodID <= "0") {
    echo("
        <h3>This Product Does Not Exist</h2>
        <table border='0'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href=catalogue.html'><button class='btn btn-info'><font color='white'>&nbsp;Add A     New product&nbsp;</font></a></button>
            </td>
            <td>                        
                <a href='manageproducts.php'><button class='btn btn-info'><font color='white'>Back to Products</font>  </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
            </table>
    ");
} else {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "cl49-xxx", "xxx");

    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    @mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con) or die("Unable to select database");
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE prodID=$prodID") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: This question doesn't belong to Java. Also, Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: Add: `ini_set('display_errors', true);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your page to get errors. Without errors this is quite anoying for people to debug for you.

Comment: What tag does this need to be `<script>`?

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new code. This interface is deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly like you have here, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. You're not [properly escaping your query parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and have a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and would have avoided this if you're disciplined about using parameterized queries.

Comment: what this gives `$prodID` ?

Comment: `$prodID = $_GET["q"];` the address bar looks like this `http://www.XX.co.uk/newc/delete_product.php?q=11122`

Comment: don't use `mysql_*` as it's deprecated, use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: @AmitMalakar still doesnt work?!??

Comment: @Shane - is that your exact code? Because you're missing the closing brace on your `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing `}` after your `$result` and before your `?>`

Answer (score 0):

you are checking math operators with strings.

use this instead. thats why you got 0 value in your delete query which is wrong

```
if ($prodID <= 0)
```

edit:

use this.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE prodID=$prodID") ;
```

instead of

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE prodID=$prodID")
```

EDIT:

try remove `@` before mysql_select_db

Comment: @DamienOvereem i have added your code,still not getting any errors??

Comment: Remove the @ infront of `mysql_select_db()` probably selecting a non existing database.

Answer (score 0):

```
"DELETE FROM products WHERE prodID='".$prodID."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $prodID = $_GET["q"];

    if ($prodID <= "0") {
        echo("
            <h3>This Product Does Not Exist</h2>
            <table border='0'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href=catalogue.html'><button class='btn btn-info'><font color='white'>&nbsp;Add A     New product&nbsp;</font></a></button>
                </td>
                <td>                        
                    <a href='manageproducts.php'><button class='btn btn-info'><font color='white'>Back to Products</font>  </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                </table>
        ");
    } else {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "cl49-xxx", "xxx");

        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }


        @mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con) or die("Unable to select database");
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM products WHERE prodID=$prodID") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```